# Clang/LLVM enabling OpenMP-Support

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, openmp

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition on Windows. My goal is to build a cross-plattform shared c++ library for mobile devices. So far i used the corresponding c++ development template.

After setting everything up i can't see how to enable openmp in the compiler. Coming from Android Studio it was sufficient to add "-fopenmp" to the compiler flags. VS seems to support equal compilers in this template gcc 4.9 and clang 3.8. I read that under "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language" there should be an option to enable OpenMP support, but in case of this template the option is not there. (I tested other c++ template which offers this possibility)

Even the compiler flag "-fopenmp", results in an "undefined reference error" of openmp. As i researched more i looked up the different toolchains which are delivered by VS, the LLVM toolchain seems not including omp header oder prebuilts.

Maybe some one can help, the code was working in android studio via cmake. I added all necessary dependencies through visual studio and installed the necessary vs packages.

Edit:
Maybe i should add that the platforms i want to build for are ARM and ARM64.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issues and maybe it helps someone. I switched the compiler to gcc in the already installed version. The issues was that i didn't set the compiler flag -fopenmp at the linker.

Now it is building, but i still don't know why clang/llvm is not working.

Comment: Do you have an llvm cross compiler to build on Windows for your targets which is built with OpenMP enabled?  If so, does it support all the features you require?

Comment: Yeah i installed a separate version of clang/llvm with omp support, but the corresponding msbuild tools seems only supporting til vs version 2014. After that i gave GCC a try again and it worked as expected.